# How to add ResourceDictionary in Bootstrapper Application

Tags: c#, wpf, bootstrapper

In my Bootstrapper Application I am using my own message box. This messagebox needs styling which is present in a `dll`. For other views (`xaml`) it is added as `ResourceDictionary` like:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyApp;component/MyStyle.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Or in general any `C#` application has `app.xaml` wherein this style can be added and it works. For Bootstrapper I am unable to add `app.xaml` or provide this `ResourceDictionary`. Any Pointers?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you have to do prior to being able to add Resource Dictionaries to the Application resources. Since the native Bootstrapper is hosting our WPF window there is no Application setup automatically. This can be done with simply creating a instance of `System.Windows.Application`. Second you have to set the `Application.ResourceAssembly`. After these two steps you are able to access the Applications Resources with `Application.Current.Resources`. For completeness a full Codesample:

```
public class CustomBootstrapper : BootstrapperApplication
{
    protected override void Run()
    {
        if (Application.Current == null)
        {
            new Application();
        }
        if (Application.ResourceAssembly == null)
        {
            var assembly = typeof(CustomBootstrapper).Assembly;
            Application.ResourceAssembly = assembly;
        }
        var myStyle = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("/styling/MyStyle.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myStyle);
        var view = new MainWindow();
        view.Show();
    }
}
```

I hope this answers your Question